# Error on SetTextSize by using settingPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, listpreference

How can I set textsize from setting preference fragment into textView? The font size is selected from a listView I will provide the code below the image.

Please see my image below: [image]

I know I am doing something wrong. Please show me a proper way to do this.

This is my font size value:

[image]

This is my listpreference:

```
<ListPreference
        android:title="Font Size"
        android:summary="Select desirable font size"
        android:key="FontSizeKey"
        android:entries="@array/select_font_size"
        android:entryValues="@array/select_font_size_value"
        android:defaultValue="24"/>
```

and also if you guys have any website/tutorial/blogs link for me to refer, it would be good.

Comment: instead of string-array, please take **integer-array**, because setTextSize take integer type of input.

Comment: ok i have changed it to integer-array. but the error still showing. pls help me its been 1 1/2 days im trying to solve this @RahulSharma

Comment: Hey I have added my answer, please go through it.

Comment: `setTextSize()` accepts an float as an argument. And you are trying to use String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value which TextView accept is `float`.  One more thing is that to get the value from SharedPreference, use KEY.

```
String setFontSize  = getSharedPreferences.getString("FontSizeKey");
setDuaText = setTextSize(Float.valueOf(setFontSize));
```

Comment: the getSharedPreferences are showing error. it says getString (string,string) cannot be applied to (string) which is mean it need 2 string than just the key ("FontSizeKey", "").

Comment: But the float value of is really WORKS Thank you

Comment: Hey @HesZrave Nice to see, it worked. Sorry for late reply my grandpa passed last night. :(

Answer (score 0):

convert string to float using this method

```
secDuaText.setTextSize(Float.parseFloat(setFontSize));
```

Answer (score 0):

From the hint its quite clear that you the method is expecting a float value. And you are passing it a string value. So either save it as a float using putDouble in your shared prefs and use getDouble and save it in a float variable. Like below

```
SharedPrefs.putDouble("FontSizeKey", 24.0);

double setFontSize = SharedPrefs.getDouble("FontSizeKey");
```

Else, just parse the String for a float value like below

```
secDuaText.setTextSize(Float.parseFloat(setFontSize));
```